# Undefined css file Error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing the issue, "Undefined CSS file". The path I have gived in correct only. But still it has showing the error.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/paramquery/pqgrid.min.css" />
<script
 src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/paramquery/pqgrid.min.js"></script>

<!--jqueryui touch punch for touch devices-->
<script
 src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/paramquery/touch-punch/touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<!--PQ Grid Office theme-->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/paramquery/themes/Office/pqgrid.css" />
```

[image: Error]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5tn5.jpg)

[image]

This issue I am facing. Please help me how can i resolve this.

Comment: The end result should be `http://your.domain.here/resources/js/jquery-ui.js`. I suppose you're opening a jsp file directly without hosting it on a server?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put Sprint MVC code in a simple jquery page unless it is rendered via a server running spring MVC, simply prepend the context path "http://stacksnippets.net/js" rather than ${pageContext.request.contextPath}